# Django Forms do not work on server but work on local machine

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, http-status-code-404

I have a Django site I have built and tested on my local machine it works fine (runserver command). When I upload it to my host, everything loads just fine but I have an issues where the form will not update and redirects me to the index page. The odd part is when it does this, it keeps the URL of the previous page i was on with the form and then form is not updated.

There are two forms affected by this issue. What I have discovered, is that on my hosted site any form with an image field in it does not update and goes to the index page.

They were set up as ImageFields and I did discover that Pillow was not installed and I was not able to get it to install properly. So I changed the fields back to FileFields and still have the same issue.

If I remove the FileFields from the forms.py form, the form is updated properly.

So I know for certain that it is the FileField.

The host I am on has terrible logging and no ssh access to do tests via the command line.

Media/Static settings from settings.py (the images do load fine on the site that are in static and media, so i believe these are correct):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..','autox','static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..','autox','media')
```

Forms.py

```
#user profile form
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    team_manager = forms.BooleanField(disabled=True, required=False)
    photo = forms.FileField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ['team','team_manager','bio','position','photo','phone','twitter','facebook','instagram']
        help_texts = {
            'team': 'If your team is not listed here, it can be created later under the user menu',
            'team_manager': 'You cannot modify this value but if it is checked, you can update the team profile',
    }

#Team form
class TeamForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['name','department','location','team_contact_email','team_contact_number','theme_song','skill_level','team_photo','team_bio','website']
```

urls.py

```
...
url(r'^updateteam/$', views.updateteam, name='updateteam'),
url(r'^accounts/profile/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
...
```

views.py

```
#profile update (issue 1)
@login_required
def profile(request):
    member = Member.objects.get(name=request.user)
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uf = UserEditForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        pf = ProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES, instance=member)
        if uf.is_valid() * pf.is_valid():
            user = uf.save()
            memberprofile = pf.save(commit=False)
            photo = request.FILES.get('photo', False)
            if photo:
                memberprofile.photo = photo
            memberprofile.name = user
            memberprofile.email = user.email
            if 'team' in pf.changed_data:
                memberprofile.team_manager = False
            memberprofile.save()
            return render(request,'registration/profile_updated.html')
    else:
        uf = UserEditForm(instance=user)
        pf = ProfileForm(instance=member)
    return render(request,'registration/profile.html',    {'userform':uf,'profileform':pf})


#team update (issue 2)
@login_required
def updateteam(request):
    member = Member.objects.get(name=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TeamForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=member.team)
        if form.is_valid():
            team = form.save(commit=False)
            photo = request.FILES.get('team_photo',False)
            if photo:
                team.team_photo = photo
            team.save()
            return redirect('packages')
        else:
            return redirect('teams')
    else:
        form = TeamForm(instance=member.team)
    return render(request, 'autox/teammanagement.html',{'form':form})
```

Lastly Models.py

```
#Member (profile issue 1)
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team,models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True) #set_null does not delete the user when deleting the team
    team_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to='members',blank=True, default='members/no-photo.png')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    facebook = models.URLField(blank=True)
    instagram = models.URLField(blank=True)

#Team (issue 2)
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    team_contact_email = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    team_contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    theme_song = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    team_photo  = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='team',     default='team/no-photo.png')
    team_bio = models.TextField()
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
```

So, I feel very confident the issue is with my FileField, I just don't see what is wrong as it is working on my local machine, just not on the server.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Check if you have hardcoded the form action url in template.

Comment: Please post the full error and traceback; it seems odd that it would say it was "raised by" your view.

Comment: @gitblame there is no actual action at all. I didn't think it required it when post to itself (<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">).

Comment: @daniel-roseman It's not giving me a traceback page, just lists the urls from my urls.py file.

Comment: @DanielRoseman it also shows "The current URL, profile/, didn't match any of these." at the bottom of my urls list. Which is correct as it does not match. It should be accounts/profile/. I am not sure why it is dropping the accounts/ part.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. How is this being served? Can you show the relevant server configuration?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am not 100% sure what you mean by that but it is being hosting through cPanel using the python setup application. They use apache as far as i know but I cannot get access to the config for it since it is on shared hosting.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ok, if i modify the urls.py and change it from accounts/profile/ to just profile/ it doesnt throw that error for whatever reason but now it is doing the exact same thing as my updateteam/ form where the URL stays in the address bar while actually redirecting me to my index page. Any thoughts on either cause?

Comment: None, I'm afraid; we'd need to see more details of the configuration. To be honest, I'd recommend getting a better hosting provider.

Comment: @DanielRoseman What type configuration details do you need? I can still ask my provider for the details.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Just discovered something odd. I have a registration form and this one works without any issues at all. This form does not have an image field in it but the other two forms I have do. Could this possibly be an incorrect configuration with my imageFields?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ok, so i have narrowed this down to the ImageField i have setup. If i remove this field my posts work again. I figured it was a media path issue but i can browse files that are in the media path without issues. Any thoughts with why my above configuration is failing with these new findings?